# Write out Request Header to Div sent via $.ajax()

Tags: jquery

I can't find a way to capture the Request Header Raw information so I can html() it to a div to show a user for my test harness what was sent and what header was sent off in my html test harness page.

I'm using the jQuery $.ajax() function to send off the request.

Comment: Usually the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) are a good starting point for these questions

Answer (score 0):

Use the [getAllResponseHeaders()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#getAllResponseHeaders%28%29) method

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        json: {}
    }
}).done(function (data, status, jqXHR) {
    var headers = jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders();
    $.each(headers.split('\n'), function (key, value) {
        $('div').append('<p>' + key + ':' + value + '</p>')
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ywsbr/)